# Arithmetic operations using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textboxes,2 is for input value and 3rd is for operand,based on operand input it should perform relevant operation.

**HTML**

```
Num1:<input type="text" value=0 id="first"  class="box1"><br>
Num2:<input type="text" value=0 id="second" class="box2"><br>
Op:<input type="text" value="+" id="oper"   class="box3"><br>
<p id="demo"><b>Sum:0.00</b></p>
```

Onload of a document focus should be on first textbox,Validation of required fields should be done and the result should be fixed to 2 decimal places.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#demo").focus();

    var x = parseInt($('#first').val());
    var y = parseInt($('#second').val());
    var z = $('#oper').val();

    $("#first,#second,#oper").onkeyup(function () {
        switch (z) {
        case ("+"):
            var a = ((x + y).toFixed(2));
            $('#demo').text("Sum:" + a);
            if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") && (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
                $('#demo').text("Sum:Enter a valid number!");
            }
            break;
        case ("-"):
            var b = ((x - y).toFixed(2));
            $('#demo').text("Sub:" + b);
            if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") && (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
                $('#demo').text("Sub:Enter a valid number!");
            }
            break;
        case ("*"):
            var c = ((x * y).toFixed(2));
            $('#demo').text("Mul:" + c);
            if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") && (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
                $('#demo').text("Mul:Enter a valid number!");
            }
            break;
        case ("/"):
            var d = ((x / y).toFixed(2));
            $('#demo').text("Div:" + d);
            if ((isNaN(x) || x == "") && (isNaN(y) || y == "")) {
                $('#demo').text("Div:Enter a valid number!");
            }
            break;
        default:
            $('#demo').text("Invalid operator");
        }
    });
});
```

Trying to fix out the errors,please anyone can help me!!

Comment: The event is `keyup` not `onkeyup`

Comment: i have changed to keyup, still its not working

Answer (score 0):

As Tushar said, the event is handled using `keyup`, not `onkeyup`.

You need to move the variable assignments into the `keyup handler`, as you want them to be re-calculated every time they change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#first").focus();

    $("#first,#second,#oper").keyup(function () {

      var x = parseInt($('#first').val());
      var y = parseInt($('#second').val());
      var z = $('#oper').val();

        switch (z) {
         ....
```

To focus on the first textbox, you want to focus on the first textbox id, rather than the p tag.

```
$("#first").focus();
```

This will then work like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue you can check on js fiddle  please tell me if you have any issue.

`link here --` http://jsfiddle.net/FHf9a/317/